# How to get the name of host sending the packet

Tags: java, multicast, hostname, multicastsocket

I wrote a java program that opens a multicast socket and gets a packet from any sender using same multicast IP.

I want know the name of the host and IP that is sending.

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0):

The source address is in the packet. In C it is available via a result argument of recv(); in Java via a method of DatagramPacket; etc.